# Given $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$, does there exist solution for $e^{i\theta_1 T} + e^{i\theta_2 T} + e^{i\theta_3 T} =0$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I came up with the following problem.
Given mutually different $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_3\in\mathbb R-\{0\}$, does there exist $T\in \mathbb R$ such that
$$e^{i\theta_1 T} + e^{i\theta_2 T} + e^{i\theta_3 T}=0?$$

For simpler problem of determining the existence of the solution of $e^{i\theta_1 T} + e^{i\theta_2 T}=0$, the answer is positive by taking $T$ such that $(\theta_1-\theta_2)T \in 2\pi\mathbb Z + \pi$. However, I could not find the answer if more terms are added.

It would be more fun if the answer can address the general case where 3 is replaced by $n$.

Comment: The summands must form an equilateral triangle, which gives conditions on the differences $\theta_i - \theta_j$.

Comment: $(\theta_2-\theta_1)T=2\pi n \pm 2\pi/3$, $(\theta_3-\theta_1)T=2\pi 
m\pm 4\pi/3$ $\Rightarrow$ 
$\frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}{\theta_3-\theta_1}=\frac{3n\pm 1}{3m\pm 2}$, 
$n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There is a solution $T$, but the solution need not be real.